# Can You Craft Magic Items At a Lower Caster Level Than Your Own?

Tags: pathfinder-1e, crafting

Many magic items have a cost based on the item's caster level, yet do not benefit from that caster level in any way. Magic Staves, for example.  When crafting such an item, can a player choose to use the minimum caster level, rather than their own?

Comment: Staves benefit from caster level if they're being used by someone other than their creator.  An 11th - or 1st - level cleric may appreciate having a staff holding a *heal* spell be higher than the minimum level.

Comment: Staves apply their USER's caster level, unlike wands.

Comment: "Unlike with other sorts of magic items, the wielder *can* use his caster level when activating the power of the staff **if it’s higher than the caster level of the staff**." Emphasis mine.  You can still use the staff's caster level if yours isn't higher.

Answer (score 9, accepted):

**Yes.**

As [Pathfinder SRD](http://paizo.com/pathfinderRPG/prd/magicItems/magicItemCreation.html) tells us,

> A creator can create an item at a lower caster level than her own, but never lower than the minimum level needed to cast the needed spell.

Comment: As a note, no item in Pathfinder actually *requires* spells to craft-- you can bypass prerequisites by adding 5 to the crafting DC.  This means you can craft even high-level staves at CL 8 (the minimum), if you can get your crafting check total high enough.

Comment: @thedarkwanderer I think the rule listed above is going to still apply even if you bypass the requirement.  You might not personally need access to the spell, but the *item* needs to at least be high enough level to cast the spell.